# Subclass Python list to Validate New Items

Tags: python, list, subclass

I want a python list which represents itself externally as an average of its internal list items, but otherwise behaves as a list. It should raise a `TypeError` if an item is added that can't be cast to a float.

The part I'm stuck on is raising `TypeError`. It should be raised for invalid items added via any list method, like `.append`, `.extend`, `+=`, setting by slice, etc.

**Is there a way to intercept new items added to the list and validate them?**

I tried re-validating the whole list in `__getattribute__`, but when its called I only have access to the old version of the list, plus it doesn't even get called initialization, operators like `+=`, or for slices like `mylist[0] = 5`.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean "represents itself as an average of its items"? Do you mean it keeps track of the average?

Comment: Yeah, has a method which computes its average or something. That part is really just context, my issues are coming from validation of new items.

Comment: Careful with terminology, to say that something "represents itself as an an average of items" implies that it tracks only the average, and not the actual items.

Comment: So the items in the list are restricted to numbers (something that can be averaged)?

Comment: Please show your code as you have it so far.

Comment: @WinstonEwert good point -- I meant "represent" in the presentation sense, not internal representation. I see it's ambiguous. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inherit from [MutableSequence](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html) and implement the methods it requires as well as any others that fall outside of the scope of Sequences alone -- like the [operators here](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html). This will allow you to change the operator manipulations for list-like capabilities while automatically generating iterators and contains capabilities.

If you want to check for slices btw you need to do `isinstance(key, slice)` in your `__getitem__` (and/or `__setitem__`) methods. Note that a single index like myList[0] is not a slice request, but a single index and myList[:0] is an actual slice request.

Answer (score 2):

The `array.array` class will take care of the `float` part:

```
class AverageList(array.array):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kw):
        return array.array.__new__(cls, 'd')
    def __init__(self, values=()):
        self.extend(values)
    def __repr__(self):
        if not len(self): return 'Empty'
        return repr(math.fsum(self)/len(self))
```

And some tests:

```
>>> s = AverageList([1,2])
>>> s
1.5
>>> s.append(9)
>>> s
4.0
>>> s.extend('lol')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#117>", line 1, in <module>
    s.extend('lol')
TypeError: a float is required
```

Comment: Cool, on the surface this looks like what I need! Give me a bit of time to play with it, and if it works I'll accept this.

Comment: Might be preferable just to give it a new method to compute the average rather than muck-up the `__repr__()` method.

Comment: Only problem is that the new class is not a subclass of `list` and therefore doesn't necessarily all have the same methods one would have (and therefore may not be compatible enough with the (underspecified) desired usage).

Answer (score 1):

There are 7 methods of the `list` class that add elements to the list and would have to be checked. Here's one compact implementation:

```
def check_float(x):
    try:
        f = float(x)
    except:
        raise TypeError("Cannot add %s to AverageList" % str(x))

def modify_method(f, which_arg=0, takes_list=False):
    def new_f(*args):
        if takes_list:
            map(check_float, args[which_arg + 1])
        else:
            check_float(args[which_arg + 1])
        return f(*args)
    return new_f

class AverageList(list):
    def __check_float(self, x):
        try:
            f = float(x)
        except:
            raise TypeError("Cannot add %s to AverageList" % str(x))

    append = modify_method(list.append)
    extend = modify_method(list.extend, takes_list=True)
    insert = modify_method(list.insert, 1)
    __add__ = modify_method(list.__add__, takes_list=True)
    __iadd__ = modify_method(list.__iadd__, takes_list=True)
    __setitem__ = modify_method(list.__setitem__, 1)
    __setslice__ = modify_method(list.__setslice__, 2, takes_list=True)
```

Comment: `__setslice__` has been deprecated since Python 2.0. Also it's bad form in new style Python to implement all of these from scratch. The better method is to inherit from a collections module abc and implement any additional features you want after that point.

Comment: @martineau: There wasn't any. Sometimes I use that while switching between StackOverflow and my text editor (so that I can indent all lines in my text editor, and work without reindenting and unindenting) and it got left in there by accident.

Comment: Oh, I see. An (simpler?) alternative would be to use the `{}` button to indent your code after pasting it into the Answer box.

Comment: Your code is only modifying seven methods. Generally I think this is a good answer and it might require even less code if you used the `collections` module for an abstract base class as @Pyrce recommended.

Comment: FWIW, I just checked and using `MutableSequence` from the `collections` module as a base class would still require implementing (a different set of) seven methods. Specfically `__setitem__, __delitem__, insert, __getitem__, __len__, __iter__, & __contains__`.

Comment: @martineu: Not sure why I originally counted 8. Thanks!

Comment: this doesn't seem to work (python 2.7): AverageList([1, 2, 'a')]

Answer (score 1):

Actually the best answer may be: don't.

Checking all objects as they get added to the list will be computationally expensive. What do you gain by doing those checks? It seems to me that you gain very little, and I'd recommend against implementing it.

Python doesn't check types, and so trying to have a little bit of type checking for one object really doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: Having type checking for elements of a custom container type might make sense.

Comment: In general I agree, but there are situations where it's nice -- i.e. early error detection where performance isn't a problem (very small problem spaces).

Comment: Well to be picky, I'm not checking type, I'm just casting to float, and in fact I may end up storing those floats instead of the objects. Is casting to float up front really going to cost much more than doing the same every time I compute the average?

Comment: @Phil: That depends on how often you compute the average vs add/change items. Validation can also reduce the need for error handling code -- assuming you bother put any in.

Comment: @Phil, then it seems to me you aren't doing validation but something more and my reasoning doesn't apply.

Answer (score 0):

The general approach would be to create your own class inheriting vom list and overwriting the specific methods like append, extend etc. This will probably also include magic methods of the Python list (see this article for details: http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html#sequence).

For validation, you will need to overwrite __setitem__(self, key, value)

Comment: I'm trying to avoid overwriting those methods, since there are at least seven to cover. I was hoping they would all call some base item editor type function that I could intercept.

Comment: I'm not concerned about the work to do it, I'm concerned with how my code looks after. Putting a simple one-method class in my simple script is fine, but a big 8+ method class definition is going to make it feel clunky. And the script is too simple to make it worth putting this in an external module....

Comment: @Phil: As you can see from David Robinson's answer, the methods don't have to be that long, nor do they have to be put in a separate file.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to create a subclass using the `MutableSequence` abstract base class in the `collections` module as its base class (not fully tested -- an exercise for the reader ;-):

```
import collections

class AveragedSequence(collections.MutableSequence):
    def _validate(self, x):
        try: return float(x)
        except: raise TypeError("Can't add {} to AveragedSequence".format(x))
    def average(self):  return sum(self._list) / len(self._list)
    def __init__(self, arg):  self._list = [self._validate(v) for v in arg]
    def __repr__(self):  return 'AveragedSequence({!r})'.format(self._list)
    def __setitem__(self, i, value):  self._list[i] = self._validate(value)
    def __delitem__(self, i):  del self._list[i]
    def insert(i, value):  return self._list.insert(i, self._validate(value))
    def __getitem__(self, i):  return self._list[i]
    def __len__(self):  return len(self._list)
    def __iter__(self):  return iter(self._list)
    def __contains__(self, item):  return item in self._list

if __name__ == '__main__':
    avgseq = AveragedSequence(range(10))
    print avgseq
    print avgseq.average()
    avgseq[2] = 3
    print avgseq
    print avgseq.average()
    # ..etc
```