# Detect changes in an array and run command for new values

Tags: python, arrays, events

I have an array of IP's that changes from time to time and i want for every new IP that comes up to run a command.

The code I have is:

```
while (network.status!="connected"):
    p=network.connections  
    for i in p:
        print i.ip  #checks the IP's in the array i
    time.sleep(10)
```

So i want whenever there is a new value in the array i to run a specific command.
What's the most efficient way to do this in python.

Comment: First of all, get rid of the ugly parentheses around the `while` condition. It's python and not C.

Comment: How are elements added to network.connections? Can't you define a method to add new IPs which at the same calls a custom handler?

Answer (score 5):

Use a [`set`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) and look at the difference in each loop:

```
old = set()
while network.status != "connected":
    p = set(network.connections)
    for i in p - old:
        print i.ip # new ips that were added
    for i in old - p:
        print i.ip # old ips that were removed
    old = p
    time.sleep(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about subclassing the list and connecting it to some handler?
Have a look here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12203829/1091116
What you want to do is to rename 'validate' and make it react to adding items in the list.