# How to count the number of calls to a method?

Tags: python

I'm working with the pi2go lite robot. This is my code

```
import pi2go, time 
import sys
import tty
import termios
import time
pi2go.init()

def stepCount():
  countL += 0
  countR += 0


speed = 60
try:
   pi2go.stepForward(60,16)
   print stepCount

finally:
   pi2go.cleanup()
```

The question is I am wondering how to count everytime the "pi2go.stepForward(60,16)" is used.

Comment: Is this your whole code? As it is it should raise numerous errors as `countL` and `countR` are not defined. Also, printing `stepCount` (or `stepCount()` as a matter of fact) will not be useful.

Comment: This link will solve the problem, the answer already exist: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21716940/is-there-a-way-to-track-the-number-of-times-a-function-is-called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
counter = dict(ok=0, fail=0, all=0)
try:
    pi2go.stepForward(60,16)
    counter['ok'] += 1
except:
    counter['fail'] += 1
finally:
    counter['all'] += 1
    pi2go.cleanup()
```

Answer (score 0):

You were very close. `stepCount` is a function, so you should call it - that is add the parentheses at the end.

```
speed = 60
try:
   pi2go.stepForward(60,16)
   stepCount()
```

Also you didn't define `countL` and `countR`. So you need to define those before hand.

But the best way would be to wrap the `pi2go.stepForward(60,16)` in another function.

Like:

```
countL = 0
countR = 0

def stepForward(x, y):
    countL += 1
    countR += 1
    pi2go.stepForward(x,y)
```

And then you can just call `stepForward(60, 16)`.

Comment: `stepCount` method does not return a value.

Comment: Calling `stepCount` will result in a `NameError`, given that OP posted all of their code.

Comment: Yes, I noticed a bit late and was updating my answer.