# Nice way to create global counters?

Tags: python, python-2.7, global-variables

I'm very unfamiliar with Python 2.x and I have some inherited code in many files where I need to count how many times some particular functions are called (to solve a particular problem).

To show what I mean, in another simple language I would do this

Add at the beginning of the code

```
counter_funcA = 0
counter_funcB = 0
...
```

In the beginning of  function A

```
counter_funcA += 1
```

In the beginning of function B

```
counter_funcB += 1
```

And so on...

And at the end

```
print counter_funcA
...
```

So how would a python expert do this in a nice way?

I guess the operation `+=` is quite atomic -- so there will not be any concurrency issues?

Comment: "I need to count how many times some particular functions are called (to solve a particular problem)" -- What kind of problem are you trying to solve?  Is this for performance debugging?  If it is, can I recommend that you use [python's profiler](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html)?  If it isn't, then it's possible that there are better solutions than global state (e.g. a decorator that manages the counts, etc.).  Can you tell us more about the problem you're actually trying to solve?

Comment: I really really like this answer to the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21717084/1870832

Comment: The decorator portion of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21717396/355230) to the same question is better IMO.

Comment: `+=` is not atomic, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1718843/7486016)