# Is attribute on function a thread-safe

Tags: python, thread-safety

I have created a bunch of functions. Each of the function may or may not internally use others. At the end of original function call I want to perform cleanup of all the mess they have created (let say we clean tmp files). To do that I have created a decorator with counter, after final function is executed counter drops to 0, cleanup is performed. But is such solution thread/process/voodoo-safe?

To better describe what I am doing I have created following working snipped:

```
import functools


def control(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            control.x += 1

            print(func.__name__)

            result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception:
            raise
        finally:
            control.x -= 1

        if control.x == 0:
            ignition()

        return result

    return inner


control.x = 0


@control
def launch():
    check_engine()
    check_control()
    check_seatbelts()


@control
def check_engine():
    print("\t - ALL GREEN")
    check_fuel()


@control
def check_fuel():
    print("\t - ALL GREEN")


@control
def check_control():
    print("\t - ALL GREEN")


@control
def check_seatbelts():
    print("\t - ALL GREEN")


def ignition():
    print("IGNITE!")


launch()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply put [lock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#lock-objects) on your function, to guarantee only one thread can modify your `x` value at a time.

```py
import functools
from threading import RLock

def control(func):
    control.lock = RLock()
    print("control.x is", control.x)
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        with control.lock:
            control.x += 1
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    
    return inner

control.x = 0


@control
def launch():
    print("You can launch me in a thread, x is safe")

print(control.x)
```