# The number of times a function gets called

Tags: python

Let's say I want to integrate `x**2` from 0 to 1. I do it using the `scipy.integrate.quad`:

```
from scipy import integrate
def f(x): return x**2
I = integrate.quad(f, 0, 1)[0]
print(I)
```

**Questions:** Is there any way to know how many times the user-defined function `f` gets called by the `quad`? I want to do it as I am interested to know how many have been utilized by `quad` to evaluate the integral.

Comment: Couldn't you just keep a count?

Comment: naive way would be to put a `print()` statement in the `f()` function and count the number of outputs. Or better, make a variable `count = 0` and increment it each time `f()` is called, and print `count` value at end of script.

Comment: Increment a global variable from inside `f`

Comment: Can you guys please gimme an example or something?

Comment: @omehoque see answers below

Comment: Does this answer your question? [is there a way to track the number of times a function is called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21716940/is-there-a-way-to-track-the-number-of-times-a-function-is-called)

Answer (score 9):

Sure. Use a call-counting wrapper:

```
import functools
def counted_calls(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def count_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        count_wrapper.count += 1
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    count_wrapper.count = 0
    return count_wrapper
```

And pass the wrapped version to `quad`:

```
wrapped = counted_calls(f)
integrate.quad(wrapped, 0, 1)
print(wrapped.count)
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/9VEhVx), with a call count of 21.

I've specifically avoided using a global counter or using `counted_calls` as a decorator on the `f` definition (though you can use it as a decorator if you want), to make it easier to take separate counts. With a global, or using it as a decorator, you'd have to remember to manually reset the counter every time.

Comment: Decorators are better than globals or class instances, good job.

Comment: I'm not a python programmer, but shouldn't you be calling `integrate.quad(wrapped, 0, 1)`? Or there is some magic?

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera: Indeed, I had a few errors. There was also an extra colon on the `@functools.wraps(f)` line.

Answer (score 4):

Just add to a global whenever `f` is called:

```
from scipy import integrate
count = 0
def f(x):
    global count
    count += 1
    return x ** 2
I = integrate.quad(f, 0, 1)[0]
print(I)
print('called', count, 'times')
```

Answer (score 4):

You could do something like this:

```
from scipy import integrate

class FWrap(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 0
    def f(self, x):
        self.count += 1
        return x ** 2

fwrap = FWrap()
f = lambda x: fwrap.f(x)
I = integrate.quad(f, 0, 1)[0]
print(I)
print(fwrap.count)
```

I prefer this to globals, though there's probably a simpler way. (EDIT: [There is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52448858/246616))

Answer (score 1):

In your small example, you can use variables or some other custom code to keep track, but if you'd rather not have to keep editing your code (maybe in a large program where you want to track many functions' calls), it'd be better to use [trace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/trace.html) and/or some call graphing library. More standard approach too, and gives you other things like timing data if you want it.

I've used this one with Gprof before and was happy with it, and it works for more than just Python: https://github.com/jrfonseca/gprof2dot

Answer (score 0):

You can add a simple counter inside the function to tally how many times the specific code was ran.

Answer (score 0):

An interesting system that I don't think has been explored in the previous (and very valid) answers, is the definition of a counter attribute (say `count`) for your function.

Since in my personal experience I've always avoided the use of global variables, this could be a simple and at the same time safer approach.

```
from scipy import integrate

def f(x):
    return x**2
    f.count += 1

f.count = 0

I = integrate.quad(f, 0, 1)[0]
print(I)
print(f.count)
```