# counter for recursive function

Tags: python, recursion, counter

this is my work function:

```
def array_sums_statistics_poss(arr, num):
    if num == 0:
       return True
   elif len(arr) == 0:
       return False
   elif num < 0:
       return False
   else:
       option1 = array_sums_statistics_poss(arr[:-1], num - arr[-1])
       option2 = array_sums_statistics_poss(arr[:-1], num)
       return option1 or option2
```

I want it to return a `list` that looks like this `[*True/False*, *X*]`, First element is a `bool` *for if there is a sub-sum list for num*, Second element is an `int` for numbers of calls, 0 if there isn't any!

`example: print(array_sums_statistics_poss([7, 6, 18, 20], 14))  ------>  [False, 23]`

Comment: You may want to look at a decorator to do the counting logic or a profiling library. Or just (_shudder_) use a global variable.

Comment: I don't actually know how to use a global variable, like where should I put it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The number of times a function gets called in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52448773/the-number-of-times-a-function-gets-called-in-python)

Comment: actually I can't add another function to the problem or use imports, only use global variable, but I have tried to put it in the function and it didn't gave me the right output