# How to count how many times a internal class method has been called through unittest?

Tags: python, unit-testing, class, methods, assert

There's a situation where I want to check how many times an internal class method has been called. I have a sensitive cloud task that must be done in a count that depends upon some circunstances. I would like to strengthen my application with an unittest to assert the number of times a specific function has been called.

To do so in a much simpler scenario, I would like to make a test in the following script:

```
class HMT:

    def __init__(self):
        self.buildedList = []

    def handle(self, string_to_explode: str):
        for exploded_part in string_to_explode.split(","):
            self.doCoolThings(exploded_part)

    def doCoolThings(self, fetched_raw_string: str):
        self.buildedList.append("Cool thing done: " + fetched_raw_string)
```

Depending on the string that I deliver to the `handle` function, the `doCoolThings` will be called N times (in this simple case, depends solely in the number of comas inside the string).

I can make a test works by just counting the number of resulting elements inside `builderList`:

```
import unittest
from HMT import HMT

class test_HMT(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.hmt = HMT()

    def test_hmt_3(self):
        string_to_test = "alpha,beta,gamma"
        self.hmt.handle(string_to_test)
        self.assertEqual(3, len(self.hmt.buildedList))

    def test_hmt_2(self):
        string_to_test = "delta,epsilon"
        self.hmt.handle(string_to_test)
        self.assertEqual(2, len(self.hmt.buildedList))
```

But in the real scenario, there's will not have an available public class list that always will match its number of elements to the times the function `doCoolThings` was called.

So, how do I check how many times the `doCoolThings` was called without needing to check the list elements count?

I know that I can just put a counter in the class that is increased each time `doCoolThings` is called and expose it externally to be checked afterwards. But I don't would like to mess up the code putting lines that is not directly related to my business rule.

After @jarmod comment, I came into this code's version:

```
def mydecorator(func):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        wrapped.calls += 1
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    wrapped.calls = 0
    return wrapped

class HMT:

    def __init__(self):
        self.buildedList = []

    def handle(self, string_to_explode: str):
        for exploded_part in string_to_explode.split(","):
            self.doCoolThings(exploded_part)

    @mydecorator
    def doCoolThings(self, fetched_raw_string: str, *args, **kwargs):
        self.buildedList.append("Cool thing done: " + fetched_raw_string)
```

And the test:

```
import unittest
from HMT import HMT

class test_HMT(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_hmt_3_dec(self):
        hmt = HMT()
        string_to_test = "epsilon,ota,eta"
        hmt.handle(string_to_test)
        self.assertEqual(3, hmt.doCoolThings.calls)

    def test_hmt_3(self):
        hmt = HMT()
        string_to_test = "alpha,beta,gamma"
        hmt.handle(string_to_test)
        self.assertEqual(3, len(hmt.buildedList))
```

But still are not working properly. When I run tests, I receive:

```
.F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_hmt_3_dec (myTest.test_HMT)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Users\danil\tmp\myDec\myTest.py", line 10, in test_hmt_3_dec
    self.assertEqual(3, hmt.doCoolThings.calls)
AssertionError: 3 != 6

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.001s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

More tests shows that the tests runs twice but the counter do not reset either in new instantiation.

Anyway, the initial idea was to dynamically put an *observer* in a internal class method and externaly fetches each time when those method is triggered (still, not something that seems to be solved using decorator).

Thanks alot for answers (and as a plus to leave powered up, if someone knows how to reset the counter in the decorator I will appreciate as well).

Comment: Perhaps you could use a 'counted' decorator to limit the modifications to the base code. Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21716940/is-there-a-way-to-track-the-number-of-times-a-function-is-called

Answer (score 1):

```
from HMT import HMT


count = 0
def counter(f):
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        global count
        count += 1
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrap


class test_HMT(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.hmt = HMT()
        
        # Add decorator.
        self.hmt_no_decorator = self.hmt.doCoolThings
        self.hmt.doCoolThings = counter(self.hmt.doCoolThings)
        
    def test_doCoolThings_count(self):
        repeat = 3               
        [self.hmt.doCoolThings() for _ in range(repeat)]

        self.assertEqual(counter, repeat)

    def tearDown(self):
        # Remove decorator.
        self.hmt.doCoolThings = self.hmt_no_decorator

        ...
```

- *doCoolThings* is not modified in the business code. You simply get the counting behaviour for testing.
- You can get rid of the global var by replacing the count var with an object.. or by doing anything else really. But does it matter in testing?