# How can I count the number of times I call a loss function?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, counter, loss-function

I personalized my own Huber loss function in the way (https://goodboychan.github.io/python/coursera/tensorflow/deeplearning.ai/2022/02/08/01-Tensorflow2-Custom-Loss-Function.html) suggests:

```
def my_huber_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    threshold = 1.
    error = y_true - y_pred
    is_small_error = tf.abs(error) <= threshold
    small_error_loss = tf.square(error) / 2
    big_error_loss = threshold * (tf.abs(error) - threshold / 2)
    return tf.where(is_small_error, small_error_loss, big_error_loss)
```

I included it in `model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=my_huber_loss, metrics=['mae'])`
and training works fine.

Now, I would like to know how many times we call this Huber loss through the training phase, so I did as [is there a way to track the number of times a function is called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21716940/is-there-a-way-to-track-the-number-of-times-a-function-is-called) suggests:

```
def my_huber_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    threshold = 1.
    error = y_true - y_pred
    is_small_error = tf.abs(error) <= threshold
    small_error_loss = tf.square(error) / 2
    big_error_loss = threshold * (tf.abs(error) - threshold / 2)
    my_huber_loss.counter +=1 #THIS IS THE NEW LINE
    return tf.where(is_small_error, small_error_loss, big_error_loss)

my_huber_loss.counter = 0 #INITIALIZE
```

However, after the whole training `print(my_huber_loss.counter)` outputs `3`:

```
results = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, validation_split=0.1, batch_size=1, epochs=numEpochs, callbacks=[earlystopper])
print(my_huber_loss.counter)
```

Prints `3`.

I know this number is not correct, since loss functions should be called more times. In addition, I added the `tf.print("--- Called Loss ---")` line in `my_huber_loss()`, and I can see how we call it several times, e.g.:

```
Epoch 1/2
--- Called Loss ---
   1/1440 [..............................] - ETA: 56:15 - loss: 0.0411 - mae: 0.2357--- Called Loss ---
--- Called Loss ---
   3/1440 [..............................] - ETA: 47s - loss: 0.0398 - mae: 0.2291  --- Called Loss ---
--- Called Loss ---
   5/1440 [..............................] - ETA: 45s - loss: 0.0338 - mae: 0.2096--- Called Loss ---
--- Called Loss ---
   7/1440 [..............................] - ETA: 46s - loss: 0.0338 - mae: 0.2110--- Called Loss ---
--- Called Loss ---
   9/1440 [..............................] - ETA: 44s - loss: 0.0306 - mae: 0.1997--- Called Loss ---
--- Called Loss ---
  11/1440 [..............................] - ETA: 43s - loss: 0.0279 - mae: 0.1893--- Called Loss ---
--- Called Loss ---
  13/1440 [..............................] - ETA: 41s - loss: 0.0265 - mae: 0.1836--- Called Loss ---
--- Called Loss ---
  15/1440 [..............................] - ETA: 41s - loss: 0.0261 - mae: 0.1824--- Called Loss ---
--- Called Loss ---
--- Called Loss ---
  18/1440 [..............................] - ETA: 39s - loss: 0.0250 - mae: 0.1783--- Called Loss ---
--- Called Loss ---
--- Called Loss ---
  21/1440 [..............................] - ETA: 38s - loss: 0.0243 - mae: 0.1764--- Called Loss ---
...
```

What is going wrong? How can I count the number of times I call a loss function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would personally use sub-classing to preserve the state. Regardless, the issue you are facing is due to using Python side effects. The [TensorFlow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function) explains why one should not rely on Python side effects like object mutation or list appends. Instead, it is recommended to use the TensorFlow operations such as `tf.print`, `assign_add`, etc.

Here is one way to fix the issue using a graph-compatible TensorFlow code:

```
def my_huber_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    threshold = 1.
    error = y_true - y_pred
    is_small_error = tf.abs(error) <= threshold
    small_error_loss = tf.square(error) / 2
    big_error_loss = threshold * (tf.abs(error) - threshold / 2)
    my_huber_loss.counter.assign_add(1) #graph-compatible tf
    tf.print("--- Called Loss ---")
    return tf.where(is_small_error, small_error_loss, big_error_loss)
```

A simple model:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, input_shape=[1,])
])
```

***batch_size=1:***  The loss function is called 6 times per epoch (data set consisting of 6 examples).

```
my_huber_loss.counter = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False) #INITIALIZE
model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss=my_huber_loss)

results = model.fit(xs, ys, batch_size=1, epochs=2, verbose=0)
print(my_huber_loss.counter)
```

Output:

```
--- Called Loss ---
--- Called Loss ---
--- Called Loss ---
--- Called Loss ---
--- Called Loss ---
--- Called Loss ---
--- Called Loss ---
--- Called Loss ---
--- Called Loss ---
--- Called Loss ---
--- Called Loss ---
--- Called Loss ---
<tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=() dtype=int32, numpy=12>
```

***batch_size=10:*** leading to only one batch of 6 examples. The loss function is called once per epoch.

```
my_huber_loss.counter = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False) #INITIALIZE
model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss=my_huber_loss)

results = model.fit(xs, ys, batch_size=10, epochs=2, verbose=0)
print(my_huber_loss.counter)
```

Output:

```
--- Called Loss ---
--- Called Loss ---
<tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=() dtype=int32, numpy=2>
```

Comment: Hey, this totally solved my problem, thanks a lot!! Now I have to read what type of data is `tf.Variable` in order to better understand this solution. I also read the link you offered and read, as you said, that: "Side effects, such as printing, adding to lists and global mutating, may behave in unexpected ways within a Function. ". One example that is mentioned is `Counter` itself. But it does not explain why this "weird side effect behaviour" happens. Do you have a snapshot of the reason? Thanks a lot again!!

Comment: First, please note that the statement "Side effects, like printing, appending to lists, and mutating globals, can behave unexpectedly inside a Function" from 
https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function#executing_python_side_effects
does not suggest a random behavior. 
Here, "behave unexpectedly" simply means that one may expect a specific output based on their Python experience, but they would may get a different output because the tensorflow graph programming is not the same as Python language. There are two phases: tracing and execution.

Comment: It can become much more clear after reading about the **tracing** concept from this subsection:
https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function#tracing

Specifically regarding your question, changing Python global and free variables counts as a Python side effect, so it only happens during tracing. https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function#changing_python_global_and_free_variables