# Is it possible to print different in a decorator in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to call the function `notice` **twice**. And here `notice` function calls a decorator.

```
def decorator(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        # print 'first' or 'second' here.
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper


@decorator
def notice():
    print("call")


notice()
notice()
```

Here what I would like to print is

```
first call
second call
```

Is it possible?

Comment: @Tomerikoo Yes, this is the answer I am looking for. https://stackoverflow.com/a/21717396/10844937

Comment: `notice` does not call the decorator. The decorator creates a new function that wraps the original `notice` function and binds that to the name `notice`. (The decorator is called *on* the original function, as if you had written `notice = decorator(notice)`.)