# How to check if a function is called for the first time or a subsequent call?

Tags: python, static-variables

I have a function

```
def compute_daily_quantities():
  # compute some quantities, one of which is the variable, value
```

After the first call to `compute_daily_quantities`, we need to add a constant, `c` to value.

How can I check if it's the first or a subsequent call to `compute_daily_quantities`?

I come from a C++ background, and in C++, we can introduce a static variable within the function to check. I know you can do something similar in Python, but are there other ways in which this can be done in Python?

The solution I was envisioning is:

```
def compute_daily_quantities():
  # compute some quantities, one of which is the variable, value
  if not hasattr(compute_daily_quantities, "is_first_call"):
    compute_daily_quantities.is_first_call = True
  else:
    value += c

  compute_daily_quantities.is_first_call = False
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21716940/is-there-a-way-to-track-the-number-of-times-a-function-is-called

Answer (score 0):

A global variable would be the simplest way to achieve this.

```
g = 0

def func(val):
    global g
    val += g
    if not g:
        g = 20
    return val


print(func(10)) # 10
print(func(10)) # 30
```

Depending on how much persistence you want, you can even go as far as to store `g` inside a file.

Edit: I just thought this through a bit more, and the better way to achieve this would be a hasattr call similar to what OP was thinking of:

```
def func(val):
    if hasattr(func, 'g'):
        val += func.g
    else:
        func.g = 20
    return val


print(func(10)) # 10
print(func(10)) # 30
```

Comment: isn't it generally considered bad practice to use global non-constant variables?

Comment: If `func` is the only thing that uses `g`, it's technically global, but "semantically" local to `func`. Such things are typically encapsulated using classes rather than global variables, though.

Comment: @David you are completely right. Global variables are just the first things that came to mind.

Comment: @chepner yes attributes are usually attached to classes, but since OP has specified that it is a function, we have to assume that it is not currently encapsulated in a class. Creating an entire class just to store a single attribute is a pretty big overhead for something that can be done very easily with a less common feature.

Comment: I would still initialize `func.g` to 0, then unconditionally add `func.g` to value *before* unconditionally setting `func.g` to 20. The custom class basically lets you hide the initialization of the attribute inside its `__init__` method.

Answer (score -1):

Rather than using a function, you might want to keep the attribute in a separate class, like this:

```py
class Computer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.is_first_call = False

    def compute_daily_quantities():
      # compute some quantities, one of which is the variable, value
      if not self.is_first_call:
        self.is_first_call = True
      else:
        value += c
```

You would then need to make sure that you only instantiated a single instance of the class, otherwise your newer classes would be instantiated with the 'first value' flag as `False`

You might be able to use a singleton pattern, or a class attribute (rather than an instance attribute) to do this in a safer way depending on how exactly you planned to use it.

Comment: Why do you think you can't add attributes to a function? Functions are objects, they have attributes.

Comment: You *can* add an attribute to a function.

Comment: You *can* add function attributes, but a separate class is usually preferable. (The intialization of the attribute just needs to be done *after* the function definition, not at the end of the body, which may just have been an indentation error in the question.)

Comment: yup, you're right, answer changed.